# How to add a list of list into excel using python xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, list, xlsxwriter

I have a list `l1=[['a','20,'30],['b','30','40']`. I want `l1` to be inserted in an Excel file with this format:

```
a   20   30
b   30   40
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you want to insert alphabets in one cell and numbers in another cell?
something like this- | a | 20,30 | ?

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 1):

Using [`worksheet.write_column()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-column) with `xlsxwriter`

```py
>>> import xlsxwriter
>>> a = [['a','20','30'],['b','30','40']]
>>> cl1 = [i[0] for i in a]                 # ['a', 'b']
>>> cl2 = [','.join(i[1:]) for i in a]      # ['20,30', '30,40']

>>> wbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Test.xlsx')
>>> wsheet = wbook.add_worksheet('Test')

>>> wsheet.write_column(0,0, cl1)
>>> wsheet.write_column(0,1, cl2)
>>> wbook.close()
```

Or

You can use pandas [`pandas.DataFrame.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html#pandas-dataframe-to-excel)

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Column1':cl1,'Column2':cl2})
>>> df
  Column1 Column2
0       a   20,30
1       b   30,40

>>> df.to_excel('a_name.xlsx', header=True, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import openpyxl
l1 = [['a','20','30'],['b','30','40']]
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb.active
le_ = len(l1)
for i in l1:
    c1 = sheet.cell(row=1,column=1)
    c1.value = i[0]
    c2 = sheet.cell(row=1,column=2)
    c2.value = ' '.join(each for each in i[1:])
wb.save("demo1.xlsx")
```

In `sheet.cell(row=1,column=1)` you can point to specific cell using row number and column number and can store data in what ever format you want

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd
l1 = [['a','20', '30'], ['b','30', '40']]
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [l[0] for l in l1],
                   'col2': [l[1:3] for l in l1]})
df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```